# Refer to entire column using variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have a find method below:

```
Sub Find_First()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    FindString = Range("s4").Value

    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Sheet3.Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                'Application.Goto Rng, True 'value found
                MsgBox Rng.Address
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found" 'value not found
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

but when I tried to change the `range("a:a")` to a variable it would give me an error. for example:

```
col = range ("a1").value    'a1 gives a,b,c,d or e
```

with `Sheet3.Range(col:col)`  'this would give me a compile error Expected : list separator or )

why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheet3.Range(col:col)` needs to be `Sheet3.Range(col & ":" & col)` then.

Alternatively you can use `Sheet3.Columns(col)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sheet.range you can use column, It should work; So try this;

```
Sub select_column()

col = Range("A1").Value
Columns(col).Select

End Sub
```

Hope this Helps...